# Change textcolor programmatically in listview who depends of arrayadapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, textcolor

I have the next estructure:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);

arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(INGR_NOTAS.this, R.layout.list_item_clickable, R.id.txtitem, arrayList);

list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

where the layout of the listview comes from list_item_clickable.xml and the textiview "txtitem" inside it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtitem"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_dropdown_dark_frame"
        android:textAlignment="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This estructure is working in a lot of classes and like Textview says, the textcolor is always white, but now I need to change the textcolor inside of the listview depending of the value of the text (sometimes white, sometimes red). So, How can I add this change without add a big impact in the rest of the code a long all the App????

Thanks for any advice!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);

arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(INGR_NOTAS.this, R.layout.list_item_clickable, R.id.txtitem, arrayList){
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtitem)).setTextColor(position % 2 == 0 ? Color.WHITE : Color.RED); // here can be your logic
        return view;
    };
};

list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

hope it helps

Comment: I tryed it, testing if I can change the color of the text from your code. I just put Color.RED inside the setTextColor, but nothing changed.

Comment: did you add strings to arrayList ?

Comment: when I add, depending of the situation I use:

Comment: when I add, depending of the situation I use:
arrayList.add(Calificacion); // where calificacion is a String
or
arrayList.add("");

Comment: but does your list output any strings ?

Comment: after add all the items the list is showed in the screen, and only if the user press a "save" button, I get all the items of the list to save it in the database.

Comment: ok, and what is the text color of strings when your list is showing and you are using the code above ?

Comment: is coming from the textview in the layout xml of my post. I deleted the line
android:textColor="@android:color/white", but now is showing the default color for that textview

Comment: try to put a breakpoint on the line ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtitem)).setTextColor(position % 2 == 0 ? Color.WHITE : Color.RED); to check if this part of code is executing

Comment: I did it, and actually never is entering inside getView method. I guess never is triguered, no idea why.

Comment: Ok, I know why now....xD. My fault, I had declared the arrayadapter in other parte of the code too. Now is working :)

Comment: Now I need to understand how works this parto of your code: (position % 2 == 0 ?     .... my logic need to pass the string to Integer and compare if the value are less or more of 40. If is less, color is Red, if is more the color is white.

Comment: you can use Integer.parse(String) method for this

Comment: yeah....now Im trying to modify the code to apply the logic. I tryed this:

Comment: TextView aux =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtitem);
                        aux.setTextColor(Integer.parseInt(aux.getText().toString()) >= 40 ? Color.WHITE : Color.RED);

but is not working

Comment: i can advice you to put every value in separate variables to be able to see all them in debugger and analyze what is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Create your own adapter that `extends ArrayAdapter` and override `getView()`. It isn't that complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.id.red);`, if based on array list item. Then create a class that extends `ArrayAdapter`, in `getView(,,)` method set the color.

example:

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item1, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
holder.textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.id.your_color);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } 
            return convertView;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

With SimpleAdapter it is also possible. Here is my solution.

```
List<Map<String, String>> detailsList = debitorRecord.getDetails();

    String[] from = {"created_at","comment","sum"};
    int[] to = {R.id.detailCreatedAt, R.id.detailComment, R.id.detailSum};
    ListAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, detailsList, R.layout.list_detail_item, from, to)
    {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detailSum);
            //Do what u want here, in my case I 
            Map<String, String> currentRow = detailsList.get(position);
            int type = Integer.parseInt(currentRow.get("type"));
            if (DebitorRecord.TYPE_PAYMENT == type) textView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            else textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);

            return view;
        }
    };

    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```